# Check if RAM port is dead

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Samsung Series 7 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

It comes with two RAM slots of 4GB, one easily accessible and one not (behind the motherboard).

I opened my laptop to change my HD for a SSD and since then my laptop only recognizes one of the RAM slots.

Is there any way for me to check if my RAM port is dead besides, getting another one and installing in that port?

Does RAM need any drivers to be recognized? (It should be recognized by default, right?)

Extra info:

It's 64 bits machine with Ubuntu 14.04.1/Windows 8.1 dual boot installation. Both operating systems have a EFI installation. Ubuntu uses grub 2.

All parts are original from the laptop, a [Samsung Series 7 NP700Z5B-S01UB laptop](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP700Z5B-S01UB-specs), except the HD that I changed for a Samsung 840 SSD

The BIOS says "RAM slot 1: 4065MB RAM **slot 2: Not Installed**".

Comment: More system information would be awesome, 32 bit or 64 bit build? Are the sticks detected in the bios menu as Alajandra suggested?

Comment: It's 64 bits, and the BIOS says "RAM slot 1: 4065MB RAM slot 2: Not Installed".

Comment: When you say "it comes with two RAM slots of 4GB" do you mean your notebook has 8GB of system memory (i.e. RAM)

Comment: hmm. Tried switching the ram between slots?

Comment: I just checked the notebook specs. It comes with 8GB of system memory. Well, in that case I guess you accidentally unseated the memory module while installing the SSD. Try opening the laptop and making sure that the RAM module is properly inserted.

Comment: I wanted to know first if there was any software based way to test the RAM, the second slot is hard to access (behind the motherboard of the laptop). If there's not, I'll try switching them tomorrow and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if the port and ram is functioning in the bios setup, if its recognized, at least the port its working(the ram can be damaged though).Since you have Ubuntu installed, in boot-grub you can test the ram more thoroughly with the memtest option.

Comment: The BIOS says "RAM slot 1: 4065MB RAM slot 2: Not Installed". How can I use memtest in grub? My Ubuntu uses grub 2.

Answer (score 2):

Move the known working RAM module into the slot in question. Check BIOS at boot. If it recognizes the RAM, slot OK, if not - slot is dead.